# Safari on mobile devices detecting text field on entire webpage

Tags: html, mobile-safari

I have found a very strange issue that seems to only affect iPhones/touch devices using the Safari browser.

When you load any page of our website, e.g. http://199.119.123.135/surety-bonds/commercial-bonds/auto_dealer_bond.htm, tapping **anywhere** on the page brings up the keyboard as if it's detecting a text field.

I've done a lot of research but couldn't find anything on the subject or how to fix it. Anyone have ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I figured it out! it's being caused by some live chat support code (LivePerson) on our website. Does anyone know of a good way to disable java script only on mobile devices? I saw a few different methods and wasn't sure which was considered best practices/most reliable.